# Express.js connection refused when accessing website from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im trying to access my node.js server from my browser, as i want to use websockets later, but im getting an

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

on the url: "http://my-website.com:3000".

Connecting to "http://my-website.com" works fine.

My app.js:

```
var app = require("express")();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("");
});
server.listen(3000);
```

I just started with node.js and express.js today, is this normal behaviour?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you start the node service on `my-website.com`? Is there a firewall running (on `my-website.com`) that might block port 3000?

Comment: yeah, node service is running. Have to check the port thing, im currently working on a solution which avoids using a port.

Comment: You will always be using a port for nodejs. Seems like a network dns setting problem than nodejs.

Comment: what should happen if i enter the site "http://my-website.com:3000" without error?